# kubectl expose pods using selector as a NodePort service via command-line

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a requirement to expose pods using selector as a NodePort service from command-line. There can be one or more pods. And the service needs to include the pods dynamically as they come and go. For example,

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rakesh        rakesh-pod1                              1/1     Running   0          4d18h
rakesh        rakesh-pod2                              1/1     Running   0          4d18h
```

I can create a service that selects the pods I want using a service-definition yaml file -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: np-service
  namespace: rakesh
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: port1
      port: 30005 
      targetPort: 30005
      nodePort: 30005 
  selector:
    abc.property: rakesh
```

However, I need to achieve the same via commandline. I tried the following -

```
kubectl -n rakesh expose pod --selector="abc.property: rakesh" --port=30005 --target-port=30005 --name=np-service --type=NodePort
```

and a few other variations without success.

*Note: I understand that currently, there is no way to specify the node-port using command-line. A random port is allocated between 30000-32767. I am fine with that as I can patch it later to the required port.*

*Also note: These pods are not part of a deployment unfortunately. Otherwise, `expose deployment` might have worked.*

So, it kind of boils down to selecting pods based on selector and exposing them as a service.

My `kubernetes` version: 1.12.5 upstream

My `kubectl` version: 1.12.5 upstream

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
kubectl expose $(kubectl get po -l abc.property=rakesh -o name) --port 30005 --name np-service --type NodePort
```

Comment: Thanks @suren. Assuming, the number of pods increase/decrease after creating the service as suggested above, then I'd need to execute/re-create the service again. Don't you think so?

Comment: np. if the labels of the pod are going to be the same, there will be no need to re-create the service.

Comment: I have added another pod `rakesh-pod3` and that's not part of the service created above. :(

Comment: several independent pods will be selected by the same service if the labels match the service's label selector. If you want to dynamically create pods, and these to be selected by the same service, you have to ensure the pods to have the same label.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a NodePort service with a specified name using `create nodeport` command:

```sh
kubectl create nodeport NAME [--tcp=port:targetPort] [--dry-run=server|client|none]
```

For example:

```sh
kubectl create service nodeport myservice --node-port=31000 --tcp=3000:80
```

You can check Kubectl reference for more:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-service-nodeport-em-

Comment: Hi @snnsnn, your answer doesn’t address the selector requirement. It doesn’t work.